# How to use sometimes rule in Laravel 5 request class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following request class:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Validator;
use Session;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class RegisterStep1Request extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set up the validation rules
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        Validator::extend('valid_date', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            $pieces = explode('/', $value);
            if(strpos($value, '/')===FALSE) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if(checkdate($pieces[1], $pieces[0], $pieces[2])) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        return [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'dob' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/|valid_date',
            'mobile' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'first_name.required' => 'The first name field is required.',
            'last_name.required' => 'The last name field is required.',
            'email.required' => 'The email address field is required.',
            'email.email' => 'The email address specified is not a valid email address.',
            'email.unique' => 'The email address is already registered with this website.',
            'dob.required' => 'The date of birth field is required.',
            'dob.regex' => 'The date of birth is invalid. Please use the following format: DD/MM/YYYY.',
            'dob.valid_date' => 'The date of birth is invalid. Please check and try again.',
            'mobile.required' => 'The mobile number field is required.',
            'password.required' => 'The password field is required.',
            'password.confirmed' => 'The confirm password field does not match the password field.'
        ];
    }

}
```

I want to add the following sometimes rule:

```
Validator::sometimes('dob', 'valid_date', function($input)
{
    return apply_regex($input->dob) === true;
});
```

How would I add this to my request class?

I have amended my rules method to the following:

```
public function rules()
{
    Validator::extend('valid_date', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $pieces = explode('/', $value);
        if(strpos($value, '/')===FALSE) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if(checkdate($pieces[1], $pieces[0], $pieces[2])) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    Validator::sometimes('dob', 'valid_date', function($input)
    {
        return apply_regex($input->dob) === true;
    });

    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'dob' => 'sometimes|required|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/|valid_date',
        'mobile' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

But I now get the following error when I submit the form:

```
FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 216:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Factory::sometimes()
```

Comment: You are using somethings the wrong way. What iyou are trying to do is custom validation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can attach a `sometimes()` rule by overriding the `getValidatorInstance()` function in your form request:

```
protected function getValidatorInstance(){
    $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

    $validator->sometimes('dob', 'valid_date', function($input)
    {
        return apply_regex($input->dob) === true;
    });

    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: On Laravel 5.4.6, this then throws: `ReflectionException in RouteSignatureParameters.php line 25: Class App\Http\Requests\<Something>Request does not exist`

Comment: Still working in 6.6. I feel passing a closure to `sometimes` should be doable from the `rules()` method. Oh well.

Answer (score 28):

There is a [documented way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation) to make changes to the request's validator instance in Laravel 5.4. You should implement the `withValidator` method for that.

Based on the example from [@lukasgeiter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30301533/1128918), you may add the following to your request class:

```
/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->sometimes('dob', 'valid_date', function ($input) {
        return apply_regex($input->dob) === true;
    });
}
```

By doing this you don't have to worry about overriding internal methods. Besides, this seems to be the official way for configuring the validator.

Comment: This is way better and it's also the right way for Laravel 5.5+

Comment: But all of this would be called _after_ validation wouldn't it? OP wants to add validation rules that would no longer be called in this case. 

It seems like this method would would help on "Things to do if validation failed (or succeeded)

Comment: @Dudemullet Nope. This won't be called after the validation.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `dob` key to the array you are returning, along with the validation ruleset to follow, including `sometimes`.

In this case:

```
'dob' : 'sometimes|required|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/|valid_date'
```

Comment: I've done this but I now get an error. I've edited my question to show what I've done and the error that I'm getting.

Comment: I think you are confusing different concepts. It sounds like you are trying to do custom validation..

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment

> I want the rule valid_date to only run if the regex rule returns true. Otherwise 
>   the valid_date rule errors if the date isnt in the right format.

```
Validator::extend('valid_date', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
       \\use the regex here instead

        if (!preg_match('/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/', $value)) return false; 


        $pieces = explode('/', $value);
        if(strpos($value, '/')===FALSE) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if(checkdate($pieces[1], $pieces[0], $pieces[2])) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });


$validator = Validator::make($data, [
   'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'dob'       => 'required|valid_date',
    'mobile'    => 'required',
    'password'  => 'required|confirmed'
]);
```

Comment: So is there a way to only run a rule if another returns true?

Comment: yeah. that's what `sometimes` is used for

Comment: @geoffs3310 From what I can see in  your code, its not very clear why you want to use `sometime`. I think what you want to use is your custom rule `valid_date`

Comment: I want the rule valid_date to only run if the regex rule returns true. Otherwise the valid_date rule errors if the date isnt in the right format.

Comment: In that case its better you include the regex `regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/` inside your custom rule `valid_date` closure