# Validating an array based on value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm passing an object to my Laravel application which contains either a url or alpha numeric input based on another parameter provided. I can't figure out how to validate the value based on the other parameter. E.g.

```
feeds: [
  0: {source: "https://www.motorsport.com/rss/all/news/", type: "user", error: false}
  1: {source: "abc-news", type: "newsapi", error: false}
  2: {source: "the-verge", type: "newsapi", error: false}
]
```

So in this case, if the `type` is user, I need to validate the URL, but if it's `newsapi` then I need to validate with a regex.

I'm using the rules in `Requests` to handle this along with the error messages to be returned. Here's the rules, obviously the last 2 representing what I'm trying to do, but without the logic of checking the type.

```
return [
    'name' => 'required|min:1|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\$%\^&\(\)\s]+$/',
    'feeds.*.source' => 'url',
    'feeds.*.source' => 'min:1|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$/',
];
```

**Answer:** 
Thanks @Ali for the answer, with that info I was able to find this post: [How to use sometimes rule in Laravel 5 request class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300119/how-to-use-sometimes-rule-in-laravel-5-request-class) and change my Request to:

```
/**
* Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
*
* @return array
*/
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:1|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\$%\^&\(\)\s]+$/'
    ];
}

/**
* Configure the validator instance.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
* @return void
*/
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->sometimes('feeds.*.source', 'url', function($data) {
        return $data->type=='user'; 
    });

    $validator->sometimes('feeds.*.source', 'min:1|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$/', function($data) {
        return $data->type=='newsapi';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **sometimes validation rule** to achive your desired functionality. In the following code name will be validated every time when you make a request and source will be validated based on the type.

```
   $validator = Validator::make($data, [
             'name' => 'required|min:1|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\$%\^&\(\)\s]+$/',

             ]); 

  $validator->sometimes('feeds.*.source','url',function($input){
        return $input->type=="user"; 
    });

    $validator->sometimes('feeds.*.source','min:1|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$/',function($input){
        return $input->type=="newsapi"
    });
```